# Git stash didn't finish applying

Tags: git, git-stash

After a stash pop only about 5 of my 50 files were changed.  Along with the few changes I got back I got a weird extra file "Y4\004%C2%F8\037UU%BC".

I do have a local history in my IntelliJ, so I can probably recover most of it, but is there any way to do this from git?

Answer (score 2):

So I think for some reason git had trouble parsing its stash.

This was the way I got around it

```
git stash STASHNUMBER show -p > out.txt
```

Replace STASHNUMBER with the number of the stash or leave it out if its the top of the stash stack.

Then

```
git apply out.txt
```

If you still have trouble you can try altering out.txt to save as many changes as you can, then try the apply again